# Switch to a ViewController inside UITabBarController from Static Library when index is unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a static library and inside project there is a UITabBarController I need to switch between view controllers.The condition is that I have UIViewControllers name but don't know its index value. How can I do it.
I have tried to get array of view controllers and find its index but It gives error.

```
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].storyboard;
    NSString *ViewtoSwitch =@"home";
    UIViewController* myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ViewtoSwitch];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
    NSString *stringToSearch = @"home:";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",stringToSearch];
    NSUInteger index = [arr  indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
              return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
            }];
    [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

but it gives error as follows:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection  (not a collection)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after suggesyion from PKT the following code is working for me.

```
NSString *ViewtoSwitch =@"home";
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    [array addObject:NSStringFromClass([[arr objectAtIndex:i] class])];
}
int index = (int)[array indexOfObject:ViewtoSwitch];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray *arr = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];`

after that

iterate arr object and use `isKindOfClass` to verify is class that what you want or not

Comment: Thanx PKT your suggestion helped me to solve the problem.